# Printing numerous values found in a struct vector with binary search

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, binary-search

I've been given the following struct:

```
struct data
{
    string code;
    string description;
    float price;
};
```

After the user has inserted the data in `data a[]`, the program is supposed to find and print products that have the price the user asks for (using binary search).

Here's what I wrote (n is the number of products inserted by the user):

```
void binary(int n, data a[])
{
    int last = 0, first = n-1, med, p;
    bool found = false;
    cout<<"\nInsert the price of the products you'd like to see: ";
    cin>>p;
    while(last <= first && !found)
    {
        med = (last + first)/2;
        if( a[med].price == p ) 
        { 
           print(med, a); 
           found = true;
        }
        else if( a[med].price > p ) 
           first = med - 1;
        else 
           last = med + 1;
    }
    if(found)
    {
        int pos = med;
        while(a[++pos].price == p)
        {
                print(pos, a);
        }
        while(a[--med].price == p)
        {
            print(pos, a);
        }
    }
    else 
        cout<<"\nThere are no products that have the price you've inserted";
}
```

The print function looks like this:

```
void print(int x, data a[])
{

    cout<<"\nCode: " << a[x].code;
    cout<<"\nDescription: " << a[x].description;
    cout<<"\nPrice: " << a[x].price;

}
```

The problem is that it doesn't print anything, except the `cout` when there are no products that have the inserted price. (so it does know when there are products that meet the criteria, but it does not print them). Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This do work for me. How does your data look?

Comment: Are the items sorted by price? For the binary search to work the items in `a[]` must be sorted by price from the lowest to the highest.

Comment: yes it was sorted in a previous function